# Recuperar ultimo id insertado mediante jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

estoy trabajando con ajax y query para hacer un insert y me funciona bien, pero necesito recuperar el ultimo id generado (el que se genero con el insert que hice) para poder enviarlo a otro formulario.

Actualmente puedo obtener ese id en el controlador con este codigo:

```
 $id_asignacion = AsignacionMaterial::latest('id', 'num_guia_despacho')->first();//retornar el ultimo id de asignacion registrado
```

pero en la funcion jquery no se como hacer para obtenerlo y enviarlo al otro formulario...

Esta es mi script:

```
<script>
   $('#formCuenta').submit(function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    name = $('#name').val();
    email = $('#email').val();
    password = $('#password').val();
    password_confirmation = $('#password-confirm').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('cuenta.store')}}",
        type:"POST",
        //dataType: 'json',

        data:{ name:name, email:email, password:password },
             success:function(response){
                console.log(response.id);
                $('#cuenta').hide();
                $('#perfil').show();
                //$('#user_id input[name="user_id"]').val(response.id);
            },
            error:function(response){
                //console.log(response);
            }
    });
 });
</script>
```

En el controlador dentro de la funcion sotre estoy intentando asi:

```
 public function store(Request $request,
                          CreatesNewUsers $creator): RegisterResponse
    {
        event(new Registered($user = $creator->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard->login($user);

        $max_id = User::max('id');

        return response()->json(['id'=>$max_id]);

        return app(RegisterResponse::class);


    }
```

Pero en la consola me retorna undefined, ademas de no hacer el insert...

Saludos a todos

Comment: hazle un return a la respuesta de tu función dentro del controlador y lo recoges en el response del success de tu función ajax

Comment: Hola @JoséVásquez mira actualize el post con el codigo que estoy intentando utilizar, el return en la funcion store

Comment: @NicolasAlmonacid no es válido tener 2 return intentando llevarse a cabo en un solo método, no funcionarán ambos y solo el primero se llevará a cabo, el segundo será ignorado

Comment: @BetaM toda la razon, recien voy viendo ese detalle...lo dejo como una funcion aparte, pero igual deberia llamarla desde el store verdad?

Comment: Si haces `console.log(response);` ¿qué obtienes?

Comment: @BetaM me muestra undefined

Comment: Pues entonces construye un condicional en el backend en el que evalúes si se ejecuta la consulta mandas el json que pones al inicio y sino entonces otro que notifique del error y evalúa que obtienes imprimiendo response en la consola